# Как выбрать 10 самых скачиваемых файлов за сегодня?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в ней всего 3 колонки `ip:fid:date`. fid - это Ид файла. Дата в юникс секундах. На выходе хотелось бы получить `fid:скачиваний` за сегодня. Пары IP:fid уникальны. Т.е нет 2х записей одинаковых.

Answer (score 2):

По дням..

```
select fid, count(*) as cnt, from_unixtime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") as _day from table group by _day, fid order by date desc, cnt desc;
```

за определенную дату.

```
select fid, count(*) as cnt from table where from_unixtime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") = "2012-06-05" group by fid order by cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select fid, count(*) from table group by date
```

вроде бы так, дальше сам...

Comment: самое главное забыли - в конец запроса добавить `LIMIT 0, 10`. Конечно, можно потом кодом извлечь 10 первых, но зачем напрягать базу даром?

Comment: не правильно. Так вы выберете все закачки которые были скачаны за секунду времени по секундно :)